# I have problems with permissions using xargs with rm

Tags: linux, pipe, xargs, rm

I have **remove.txt** file containing **a.txt** and **b.txt** as text. All files are in the same folder, I set chmod 777 for all those files. Now, when I run **sudo cat remove.txt | xargs rm** I get Permission denied for deletion of those two files listed in **remove.txt**. What am I doing wrong? I guess question now would be where to put sudo?

Comment: `for all those files.` what about the directory they are in?

Comment: For deletion of a file, the permissions of the directory are relevant, not the permissions of the file. Please [edit] your question and show the output of `ls -ld . a.txt b.txt`. If you want to run `rm` as root you would need `cat remove.txt | sudo xargs rm` or without the probably useless `cat`:  `sudo xargs rm < remove.txt`

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been following some tutorial and got stuck at xargs. cat remove.txt | sudo xargs rm  did it. and sudo xargs rm < remove.txt. I guess I have to know where to put sudo when dealing with inputs to another command.

Comment: You should be very careful with xargs and rm . There are two security issues here: (1) if you don't control the generation of 'remove.txt' tightly, someone may inject a filename you really don't want to remove, such as /tmp/passwd. (2) xargs relies on newlines and whitespaces, but your filenames may contain special characters and whitespaces. A safer approach is to use '\0' characters as delimiters, and call `xargs -0 rm` instead.  To see what I mean, try out: `touch a b "a b" ; echo "a b" | xargs ls -l` which will show two files, instead of the original "a b" file.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo cat remove.txt |  xargs sudo rm
```